# Find and replace String with a substring result

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I was asked this recently, and I couldn't figure out the best way. We are trying to replicate Google's search results where the search terms are bolded (using a b tag) in the results.

```
Input                       Terms               Output
The search is cool          {sea}               The <b>sea</b>rch is cool
```

Originally, I thought this was pretty easy:

```
String results(String input, String[] terms)
{
   for(String term : terms)
   {
      input = input.replace(term, "<b>" + term + "</b>");
   }

   return input;
}
```

However, this isn't correct. For example:

```
Input                       Terms               Output
The search is cool          {sea, search}       The <b>search</b> is cool
```

I struggled to figure out the best way to approach this. Obviously we can no longer find and replace immediately. I played around with using a `Map<Integer,String>` where the key is the term and the value is the index returned by `input.indexOf(term)`, but this seemed potentially unnecessary. Any improvements?

```
public String results(String input, String[] terms)
{
   Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
   for(String term : terms)
   {
      int index = input.indexOf(term);
      if(index >= 0)//if found
      {
          String value = map.get(index);
          if(value == null || value.length() < term.length())//use the longer term
              map.put(index, term);
      }


   }

   for(String term: map.values())
   {
       input = input.replace(term, "<b>" + term + "</b>");
   }

   return input;
}
```

Comment: If it's already working, you should post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: first sort the terms from shortest to longest and remove duplicates, then do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  import java.net.*;
  import java.util.HashMap;
  import java.util.Map;
  import java.io.*;
  public class main {

public static String results(String input, String[] terms)
{

   for(String t : terms)
   {
       input = input.replace(t, "<b>" + t + "</b>");
   }

   return input;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] terms={"sea", "search"};
    String s = results("The search is cool ",terms);
    System.out.println(s);
    String [] terms2={"search", "sea"};
    String s2 = results("The search is cool ",terms2);
    System.out.println(s2);
}
 }
```

Output

```
 The <b>sea</b>rch is cool 
 The <b><b>sea</b>rch</b> is cool
```

In your code you were adding two times the string in the same index in the hash map so it was actually replacing "sea" to 'search" in the hash map itself.because the index is 4 in the both the cases.

```
 Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
 for(String term : terms)
 {
  int index = input.indexOf(term);
  if(index >= 0)//if found
  {
      String value = map.get(index); //the index is 4 here both the times
      if(value == null || value.length() < term.length())
          map.put(index, term);//so first time putting string sea at index 4 and in second iteration replacing "sea" to "search" at the same index 4 in hashmap because you want a longer term
  }
 }

for(String term: map.values())//here getting only one string which is "search"
{
   input = input.replace(term, "<b>" + term + "</b>");
}
```

But if you want a  longer term than it is working fine in your code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it with regular expressions.

```
public static String results(String input, String[] terms) {
    String output = input;
    Arrays.sort(terms);
    for (int i = terms.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        String term = terms[i];
        output = output.replaceAll("(?<!>)\\b" + term, "<b>" + term + "</b>");
    }
    // With regular expressions.
    // \\b = word boundary, starting at words
    // (?<X) = without preceding X (negative look-behind)
    // Converting " searching " to " <b>search</b>ing ",
    // Not converting " research ".
    return output;
}
```

The solution is a reverse sort, so that "search" precedes "sea", and checking that no ">" precedes the word (= already replaced; with a longer term).

I have added a word boundary check, that is, terms should be at the beginning of words. Not necessary.

Mind the array parameter `terms` gets sorted.